# GetStaticMethodID is missing in j2sdk1.4.2_16

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface

After reinstall my PC I found that I can't compile my project that runs using `Java 1.4`. Project was running on my old PC without problems. Currently I have error:

```
Error   4   error C2039: 'GetStaticMethodID' : is not a member of 'JNIEnv_'
```

I can't find`jmethodID GetStaticMethodID(jclass clazz, const char *name,const char *sig)` function of structure JNIEnv_ in jni.h version `j2sdk1.4.2_16`. This function available in jni.h of version `jdk1.7.0_01`.

What might be wrong? Is there something wrong with new Java installations? I suppose I can't use newer jni.h with older java lib.

There are top comment lines of jni.h version **j2sdk1.4.2_16**

```
/*
 * @(#)jni.h    1.55 03/01/23
 *
 * Copyright 2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * SUN PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
 */

/*
 * We used part of Netscape's Java Runtime Interface (JRI) as the starting
 * point of our design and implementation.
 */

/******************************************************************************
 * Java Runtime Interface
 * Copyright (c) 1996 Netscape Communications Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *****************************************************************************/
```

There are top comment lines of jni.h version **jdk1.7.0_01**

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1996, 2006, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
 */

/*
 * We used part of Netscape's Java Runtime Interface (JRI) as the starting
 * point of our design and implementation.
 */

/******************************************************************************
 * Java Runtime Interface
 * Copyright (c) 1996 Netscape Communications Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *****************************************************************************/
```

Comment: earlier version of java = ? current version of java = ?

Comment: I'm testing my application with many versions of java that are installed in my PC. I don't remember exactly, earlier I was using oldest java's versions 1.4.2_04 and 1.4.2_16 (don't remember they was SDK or not). Currently I'm running project on jdk1.7.0_01 without problem and got misunderstanding with j2sdk1.4.2_16.

Comment: glad that now things are clear

Comment: but I need to run it on j2sdk1.4.2_16 on new PC also

Comment: I don't follow this. You say above that `GetStaticMethodID()` *isn't* in jni.h version j2sdk1.4.2_16. It is definitely there in the JNI 6 specification, and it is also there in the Sun JNI book dated 1999 which goes back to Java 1.1.x. So if your code ran under 1.4.2 and it isn't there in 1.4.2's jni.h, (1) how did you ever compile it? and (2) why are you recompiling now under 1.4.2?

Comment: (1) I can't compile this for 1.4.2_16 - this is my problem. (2) I need my application to work with most java versions